# User-defined function for finding max of 4 numbers

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, awk, function

I have a basic script to find the max of 2 numbers using a user-defined function; but, I need to convert it to accept 4 numbers, and I am having a hard time.  Here is the script.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo $1 $2 | awk '
{
    print max($1, $2)
}

function max(a, b) {
    return a > b ? a: b
}'
```

You would simply execute it by doing: `./scriptname 1 2` (or whatever two numbers you want) and the output would be the max of the two numbers. 
I think I can just do the following.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo $1 $2 $3 $4 | awk '
{
    print max($1, $2, $3, $4)
}

function max(a, b, c, d) {
    return a < b ? a: b
}'
```

I am having trouble with line 7, the "return" line.  Any suggestions?
Thanks
-CableGuy

Comment: And? Edit it, and look at the preview before submitting.

Comment: Just a heads-up; your title says "finding max of 4 numbers", your initial function says & computes the max, but then your final script/function both say & compute the *minimum*.

Comment: Yeah i see that, i just forgot to modify it from the original minimum function

Comment: I fixed the min to max

Comment: If we have `max2(a,b)` returning the max of inputs, and want `max4(a,b,c,d)` returning max of inputs. Then not that `max4(a,b,c,d)` = `max2(max2(a,b),max2(c,d))` or equivalently  `max2(max2(max2(a,b),c),d)`

Comment: Thanks everyone for the edits, assistance and feedback on how to use the site. I am brand new and made a lot of mistakes so, sorry about that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the 2-argument function - *multiple times*:

```
$ cat scriptname 
#!/bin/bash
echo $1 $2 $3 $4 | awk '

function min(a, b) {
    return a < b ? a: b
}

{
    print min(min(min($1,$2),$3),$4)
}'
```

then for example

```
$ ./scriptname 3 1.2 -0.4 77
-0.4
```

---

If you're required to write it as a 4-argument function, then I'd suggest something like

```
function min(a, b) {
    return a < b ? a : b
}

function min4(a,b,c,d) {
    return min(min(min(a,b),c),d)
}

{
    print min4($1,$2,$3,$4)
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you don't mind using Bash instead of AWK:

```
find_max() {
  local max number

  max="$1"

  for number in "${@:2}"; do
    if ((number > max)); then
      max="$number"
    fi
  done

  printf '%d\n' "$max"
}
```

Usage:

```
$ find_max 12 64 2 455 23 99
455
```

Comment: I have to use AWK unfortunately

Comment: @cableguy5533 I see. I've added an `awk` tag but I recommend you to state this in the question itself. I'd be glad to provide an awk-only answer if I knew it. Good luck and welcome to Unix & Linux.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this awk :

```
echo -3.89 -1.2 -0.217 -48 | awk '{a=$1;for(i=2;i<=NF;i++)a=$i>a?$i:a;print a}'
```

Answer (score 0):

The [*num-utils* package](http://suso.suso.org/programs/num-utils/) includes `numbound` which solves the general problem, (it's not limited to 4 args):

```
printf "%s\n" 5 88.3 22 -22 -333 5 | numbound
```

Output:

```
88.3
```

That can be made into a simple function that parses command line arguments:

```
max() { printf "%s\n" "$@" | numbound ; }
```

Example:

```
max 55 33 2 99 22
```

Output:

```
99
```